# VSCode Intellisense doesn't work until rebuild

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, intellisense

I have a issue with VSCode C++ Intellisense. Red error squiggles of lines isn't removed after fixing the issue until I re-build the project.

I'm using CMake as configurationProvider for Intellisense and don't want to override any settings for Intellisense. Because I want to test my applications on multiple devices simultaneously, I don't want to set compiler specific settings in .vscode folder (I want every setting to live in CMakeLists.txt).

```
//CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

file(GLOB_RECURSE DependentTuranLibs "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/TAPI/TAPI/*.cpp" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/TGFXCORE/TGFX/*.cpp")
add_compile_definitions (TAPI_THREADING TAPI_BITSET TAPI_FILESYSTEM TAPI_LOGGER TAPI_PROFILER)
file(GLOB_RECURSE VKbackendfiles "*.cpp" "*.h")
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/TAPI)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/TGFXCORE)

add_library(TGFXVulkan SHARED ${VKbackendfiles} ${DependentTuranLibs})
set_target_properties(TGFXVulkan PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set_target_properties(TGFXVulkan PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

target_compile_definitions(TGFXVulkan PRIVATE
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:VULKAN_DEBUGGING>
)


find_package(glfw3 3.3)
find_package(glfw3 CONFIG)
if(GLFW_FOUND OR glfw3_FOUND)
    include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(TGFXVulkan glfw)
else()
    message ("GLFW isn't found, please be sure to include and link GLFW3 to the project!")
endif()

find_package(glm)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
if(VULKAN_FOUND)
include_directories(${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(TGFXVulkan Vulkan::Vulkan)
else()
message("Vulkan isn't found, please be sure to install Vulkan SDK then include and link Vulkan to the project!")
endif()
```

If I switch back to GCC compiler, everything works fine. Visual Studio 2019 Community version is installed.

```
# This is the CMakeCache file.
# For build in directory: d:/dev/TuranLibraries/build
# It was generated by CMake: C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe
# You can edit this file to change values found and used by cmake.
# If you do not want to change any of the values, simply exit the editor.
# If you do want to change a value, simply edit, save, and exit the editor.
# The syntax for the file is as follows:
# KEY:TYPE=VALUE
# KEY is the name of a variable in the cache.
# TYPE is a hint to GUIs for the type of VALUE, DO NOT EDIT TYPE!.
# VALUE is the current value for the KEY.

########################
# EXTERNAL cache entries
########################

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_AR:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/lib.exe

//Semicolon separated list of supported configuration types, only
// supports Debug, Release, MinSizeRel, and RelWithDebInfo, anything
// else will be ignored.
CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES:STRING=Debug;Release;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=/MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=/MD /O1 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=/MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=/MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG

//Libraries linked by default with all C++ applications.
CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES:STRING=kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib

//Flags used by the C compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING=/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3

//Flags used by the C compiler during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=/MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1

//Flags used by the C compiler during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=/MD /O1 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the C compiler during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=/MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the C compiler during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=/MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG

//Libraries linked by default with all C applications.
CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIBRARIES:STRING=kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib

//Flags used by the linker during all build types.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/machine:x64

//Flags used by the linker during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//Flags used by the linker during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE

//Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories.
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:/Program Files/TuranLibraries

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/link.exe

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// all build types.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/machine:x64

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_MT:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/bin/10.0.19041.0/x64/mt.exe

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION:STATIC=

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_HOMEPAGE_URL:STATIC=

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME:STATIC=TuranLibraries

//RC compiler
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/bin/10.0.19041.0/x64/rc.exe

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS:STRING=-DWIN32

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-D_DEBUG

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during all build types.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/machine:x64

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//If set, runtime paths are not added when installing shared libraries,
// but are added when building.
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=NO

//If set, runtime paths are not added when using shared libraries.
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:BOOL=NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during all build types.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/machine:x64

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//If this value is on, makefiles will be generated without the
// .SILENT directive, and all commands will be echoed to the console
// during the make.  This is useful for debugging only. With Visual
// Studio IDE projects all commands are done without /nologo.
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=FALSE

//Dependencies for the target
TGFXVulkan_LIB_DEPENDS:STATIC=general;Vulkan::Vulkan;

//Value Computed by CMake
TuranLibraries_BINARY_DIR:STATIC=D:/dev/TuranLibraries/build

//Value Computed by CMake
TuranLibraries_IS_TOP_LEVEL:STATIC=ON

//Value Computed by CMake
TuranLibraries_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=D:/dev/TuranLibraries

//Path to a program.
Vulkan_GLSLANG_VALIDATOR_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=C:/VulkanSDK/1.2.189.2/Bin/glslangValidator.exe

//Path to a program.
Vulkan_GLSLC_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=C:/VulkanSDK/1.2.189.2/Bin/glslc.exe

//Path to a file.
Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=C:/VulkanSDK/1.2.189.2/Include

//Path to a library.
Vulkan_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=C:/VulkanSDK/1.2.189.2/Lib/vulkan-1.lib

//The directory containing a CMake configuration file for glfw3.
glfw3_DIR:PATH=glfw3_DIR-NOTFOUND

//The directory containing a CMake configuration file for glm.
glm_DIR:PATH=glm_DIR-NOTFOUND


########################
# INTERNAL cache entries
########################

//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_AR
CMAKE_AR-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//This is the directory where this CMakeCache.txt was created
CMAKE_CACHEFILE_DIR:INTERNAL=d:/dev/TuranLibraries/build
//Major version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MAJOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=3
//Minor version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MINOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=21
//Patch version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_PATCH_VERSION:INTERNAL=3
//Path to CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe
//Path to cpack program executable.
CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cpack.exe
//Path to ctest program executable.
CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/ctest.exe
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES
CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS
CMAKE_C_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIBRARIES
CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIBRARIES-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Executable file format
CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_FORMAT:INTERNAL=Unknown
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Name of external makefile project generator.
CMAKE_EXTRA_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator.
CMAKE_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=Visual Studio 16 2019
//Generator instance identifier.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_INSTANCE:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community
//Name of generator platform.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM:INTERNAL=x64
//Name of generator toolset.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET:INTERNAL=host=x64
//Source directory with the top level CMakeLists.txt file for this
// project
CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY:INTERNAL=D:/dev/TuranLibraries
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_LINKER
CMAKE_LINKER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MT
CMAKE_MT-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//number of local generators
CMAKE_NUMBER_OF_MAKEFILES:INTERNAL=5
//Platform information initialized
CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_INITIALIZED:INTERNAL=1
//noop for ranlib
CMAKE_RANLIB:INTERNAL=:
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_COMPILER
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER_WORKS:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to CMake installation.
CMAKE_ROOT:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Details about finding Vulkan
FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_Vulkan:INTERNAL=[C:/VulkanSDK/1.2.189.2/Lib/vulkan-1.lib][C:/VulkanSDK/1.2.189.2/Include][v()]
//ADVANCED property for variable: Vulkan_GLSLANG_VALIDATOR_EXECUTABLE
Vulkan_GLSLANG_VALIDATOR_EXECUTABLE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: Vulkan_GLSLC_EXECUTABLE
Vulkan_GLSLC_EXECUTABLE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR
Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: Vulkan_LIBRARY
Vulkan_LIBRARY-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
```

Comment: There is no way to reproduce this with the level of detail in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the CMakeLists.txt. Added it!